# on click show text field (input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of all I say to all that I am new in Web line. Now my Question is that, I need a text field like that:
**[Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V103I.jpg)**
When I fill this field now I want to add one another name so that I will click on this plus button (show in image) and one another field appear and this plus button will be hidden from that place and will appear with 2nd field like this:
**[Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDMPT.jpg)**
And if I want to adding 30, 50, 60 name the process will be going same.
Like this: i.imgur.com/styvKvN.jpg

Comment: what have you tried so far?? you have tried creating it or not? or just asking here for someone to create it for you?? if you have tried any code then please feel free to share with us..

Comment: Next time please: Ask a **question** and provide the **code**, however I'm not even sure if you have code yet, as it appears you want someone to create your idea. Voted as unclear.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. You are expected to show code that you tried to resolve your issues. Also post html not images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using **[`insertBefore()`](https://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)**

1. Add a local variable `i=1` to create name attribute.
2. Bind click event handler to button using **[`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/)**
3. Insert input field before the button using **[`insertBefore()`](https://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)**

   ```js
   var i = 1;
   $('.button').click(function() {
     $('<br/><input name="name' + (++i) + '" type="text"/>').insertBefore(this);
   });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div>
     <input name="name1" type="text" /><button class="button">+</button>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: much easier way than mine! +1 :)